# Maze problem with dfs in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, search, jupyter-notebook, depth-first-search, maze

My file name is maze1.txt which has the maze made in it. I want to solve the maze using dfs and have made stack and queue frontiers for it with various functions. Originally, this code was in .py and i tried to change it to .ipynb. I keep getting ValueError: No axis named A for object type DataFrame. I don't know how to correct this. The following is the code i have come up with so far. I don't know how to call the Maze class and proceed further to get a result. I am very new at this..

```
import sys
from sys import argv
import os
import pandas as pd

# Class node that keeps track of state, the state of state (parent) and action. No path cost as we can calculate it in the end.
class Node():
    def __init__(self, state, parent, action):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.action = action
```

```
# Stack Frontier class that generates objects. We create object and fns on the object that stores all the data of frontier
class StackFrontier():
    def __init__(self): # Creates a frontier which is empty
        self.frontier = []

    def add(self, node): # Adding nodes to frontier
        self.frontier.append(node)

    def contains_state(self, state): # Checks the state of the frontier
        return any(node.state == state for node in self.frontier)

    def empty(self): # Checks if frontier is empty, if it is empty the length of the frontier is zero.
        return len(self.frontier) == 0

    def remove(self): # Remove something from frontier after checking if it's empty or not
        if self.empty():
            raise Exception("empty frontier")
        else:
            node = self.frontier[-1] # Removes last item of the list (LIFO Structure)
            self.frontier = self.frontier[:-1] # Updating the frontier to say that go ahead and remove the node that was removed from frontier
            return node
```

```
# Queue Frontier class like Stack frontier. This inherits Stack's functions. We only readjust the remove function into FIFO
class QueueFrontier(StackFrontier):

    def remove(self):
        if self.empty():
            raise Exception("empty frontier")
        else:
            node = self.frontier[0] # Removes first item of the list (FIFO Structure)
            self.frontier = self.frontier[1:] # Updation of frontier 
            return node
```

```
class Maze():

    # Takes a txt file as an input
    def __init__(self, filename):

        # Read file and set height and width of maze
        file_path = 'maze1.txt'
        contents = pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter = "\t")

        # Validate start and goal
        if contents.count("A") != 1:
            raise Exception("maze must have exactly one start point")
        if contents.count("B") != 1:
            raise Exception("maze must have exactly one goal")

        # Determine height and width of maze
        contents = contents.splitlines()
        self.height = len(contents)
        self.width = max(len(line) for line in contents)

        # Keep track of walls
        self.walls = []
        for i in range(self.height):
            row = []
            for j in range(self.width):
                try:
                    if contents[i][j] == "A":
                        self.start = (i, j)
                        row.append(False)
                    elif contents[i][j] == "B":
                        self.goal = (i, j)
                        row.append(False)
                    elif contents[i][j] == " ":
                        row.append(False)
                    else:
                        row.append(True)
                except IndexError:
                    row.append(False)
            self.walls.append(row)

        self.solution = None


    def print(self):
        solution = self.solution[1] if self.solution is not None else None
        print()
        for i, row in enumerate(self.walls):
            for j, col in enumerate(row):
                if col:
                    print("█", end="")
                elif (i, j) == self.start:
                    print("A", end="")
                elif (i, j) == self.goal:
                    print("B", end="")
                elif solution is not None and (i, j) in solution:
                    print("*", end="")
                else:
                    print(" ", end="")
            print()
        print()


    def neighbors(self, state):
        row, col = state
        candidates = [
            ("up", (row - 1, col)),
            ("down", (row + 1, col)),
            ("left", (row, col - 1)),
            ("right", (row, col + 1))
        ]

        result = []
        for action, (r, c) in candidates:
            if 0 <= r < self.height and 0 <= c < self.width and not self.walls[r][c]:
                result.append((action, (r, c)))
        return result


    def solve(self):
        """Finds a solution to maze, if one exists."""

        # Keep track of number of states explored
        self.num_explored = 0

        # Initialize frontier to just the starting position
        start = Node(state=self.start, parent=None, action=None)
        frontier = StackFrontier() # DFS Algo used here 
        frontier.add(start) # Has start state

        # Initialize an empty explored set
        self.explored = set() # Explore set

        # Keep looping until solution found
        while True: # The repeat part 

            # If nothing left in frontier, then no path
            if frontier.empty():
                raise Exception("no solution")

            # Choose a node from the frontier
            node = frontier.remove()
            self.num_explored += 1 # Adding one to the number of states explored

            # If node is the goal, then we have a solution
            if node.state == self.goal:
                actions = []
                cells = []
                # Follow parent nodes to find a solution
                while node.parent is not None:
                    actions.append(node.action)
                    cells.append(node.state)
                    node = node.parent
                actions.reverse()
                cells.reverse()
                self.solution = (actions, cells)
                return

            # Mark node as explored
            self.explored.add(node.state)

            # Add neighbors to frontier (Exploration)
            for action, state in self.neighbors(node.state):
                if not frontier.contains_state(state) and state not in self.explored:
                    child = Node(state=state, parent=node, action=action)
                    frontier.add(child)


    def output_image(self, filename, show_solution=True, show_explored=False):
        from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
        cell_size = 50
        cell_border = 2

        # Create a blank canvas
        img = Image.new(
            "RGBA",
            (self.width * cell_size, self.height * cell_size),
            "black"
        )
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

        solution = self.solution[1] if self.solution is not None else None
        for i, row in enumerate(self.walls):
            for j, col in enumerate(row):

                # Walls
                if col:
                    fill = (40, 40, 40)

                # Start
                elif (i, j) == self.start:
                    fill = (255, 0, 0)

                # Goal
                elif (i, j) == self.goal:
                    fill = (0, 171, 28)

                # Solution
                elif solution is not None and show_solution and (i, j) in solution:
                    fill = (220, 235, 113)

                # Explored
                elif solution is not None and show_explored and (i, j) in self.explored:
                    fill = (212, 97, 85)

                # Empty cell
                else:
                    fill = (237, 240, 252)

                # Draw cell
                draw.rectangle(
                    ([(j * cell_size + cell_border, i * cell_size + cell_border),
                      ((j + 1) * cell_size - cell_border, (i + 1) * cell_size - cell_border)]),
                    fill=fill
                )

        img.save(filename)
```

I expect the program to run smoothly and be able to call the functions with the Maze1.txt file. This code should solve the Maze problem using DFS but in a jupyter notebook.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).